# Can't build json.me from the available source code

Tags: json, jar, java-me

I need to use json in my Java ME project. I have found a few tutorials that look promising , but I haven't been able to find the jar that is used.

These are two of the links I found with the source code:

https://bitbucket.org/liedman/json-me
https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me

I tried to generate the jar using the source code downloaded from those links, I even installed Maven , but all I get is erros like this :

[image]

Does anyone of you  still have the jar? If so, could you share it??

Please I really need to use this jar since I've realized it is the easiest way to work with json in j2me and I really apreciate if you could help me finally get this jar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to do the same last year, but since I couldn't do it, I have to use KXML2 :(

Comment: If I google "unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath" I get a lot of results with suggested solutions.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/537209/Howplustoplusfixplusbuildpluserror-Unableplustoplu I even  reinstalled the jdk, but the problem remains :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in the end I managed to find the jar and it works great.

Here's the link in case anyone needs it :

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonmejar.htm